# FOSUserBundle: Success target after password reset according to roles

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

After the user did reset his password using the password reset of FOSUserBundle, by default he is redirected to the FOSUserProfile. I want to redirect to a different route according to their role. Is this possible and if yes, how?
 I do this code but it redirect all kind of users

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class PasswordResettingListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS => 'onPasswordResettingSuccess',
        ];
    }

    public function onPasswordResettingSuccess(FormEvent $event) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('homepage');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

And then I registering it as a service with

```
services:
    acme_user.password_resetting:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\PasswordResettingListener
        arguments: [ "@router" ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

Answer (score 0):

Based on your version of Symfony you can choose one of the approaches described in: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

For example you can use `security.authorization_checker` service:

Inject it into your service:

```
services:
    acme_user.password_resetting:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\PasswordResettingListener
        arguments: [ "@router",  "@security.authorization_checker" ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Then in your actual service:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class PasswordResettingListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $router;
    private $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker) {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS => 'onPasswordResettingSuccess',
        ];
    }

    public function onPasswordResettingSuccess(FormEvent $event) {

        //$url = $this->router->generate('homepage');
        //$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));

        if (false === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) { 
           // redirect somewhere
        } else {
           // redirect elsewhere
        }


    }
}
```